# Which NN models does spaCy actually implement? What determines their size in memory?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have seen that there is a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06388) supplying the idea behind [Sense2Vec](https://explosion.ai/blog/sense2vec-with-spacy), but how are/were  the standard spaCy models created in the first place? When I download something like the standard "en_core_web_md" model from [the selection of models](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models), how was that actually created? Are there any papers I can read or spaCy blog posts?

**Bonus question:**

How are the new models in the upcoming `spaCy 2.0` so much smaller in size?

From the [version 2 Release summary](https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/v2#features-models):

> This release features entirely new deep learning-powered models for spaCy's tagger, parser and entity recognizer. The new models are 20x smaller than the linear models that have powered spaCy until now: from 300 MB to only 15 MB.

the only real reference that goes in this direction is [here](https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/v2#features-models) on the release summary.
The summary of all model memory footprints can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models).

Are the model weights provided and every call to get relevant attributes actually being *computed* on the fly? That would explain the slower throughput shown in the benchmarks on [this page](https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/training-ner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the releases in the models github repo https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases, there are details on each part of the model, e.g. the tagger or parser, stating what data it was trained on and what the accuracy of the resulting model is:

**Parser**: OntoNotes 5,    91.5% Accuracy

**Tagger**: OntoNotes 5,    96.9% Accuracy

**NER**:    OntoNotes 5,    84.7% Accuracy

**Word vectors**:   Common Crawl

More details on the code necessary to train the model can be found here: http://spacy.io/docs/usage/training. There is also source code attached to the releases linked above, but I haven't checked what code that is.

---

Edit:

After reading through the [discussion following the announcement of v2.0](https://github.com/explosion/spacy/issues/1105), I came across an issues that explains how the new NN models work internally.

You can find it here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1057

Comment: Great, thanks - your edit supplies most the info I was looking for!